# What are the requirements for binding data to a combobox in WPF? I can't get it to work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, observablecollection

I have a DataContext object:

```
//Simple DataContext object with an observable collection and a property representing the currently selected project which uses the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
public class ProjectManager: ObservableObject
{
   public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects {get;set;}

   public ProjectManager()
   {
       //Assignment occurs in constructor and never changes, so I don't think "Projects" property needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  It has a value by the time anything else could possibly reference it and it's always the same collection which will have items added and removed from it
       Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
   }
   private Project loadedProject = null;
   public Project CurrentProject
   {
       get {return loadedProject;}
       set
       {
           LoadProject( value ); //load the project before updating internal variable
           SetProperty( ref loadedProject, value ); //SetProperty uses C# 5.0 [CallerMemberName] attribute on optional parameter to obtain "CurrentProject" property name since it's the caller; this is a popular implementation of ObservableObject
       }
   }
}
```

I have a class representing an item in the observable collection:

```
public class Project: ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get {return _name;}
        set {SetProperty( ref _name, value );} //ObservableObject implements INotifyProperyChanged
    }
}
```

The ObservableObject is implemented here:

```
public class ObservableObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //C# 5.0 feature: "CallerMemberName" must be affixed to *optional* parameter and is automatically filled in with the member name of the method that calls SetProperty when the parameter is omitted
    protected bool SetProperty<T>( ref T prop, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(prop,value)) return false;
        prop = value;
        OnPropertyChanged( propertyName );
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

A ProjectManager instance is assigned to my Window's DataContext property in XAML like so:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <p:ProjectManager />
</Window.DataContext>
```

At runtime, the debugger's local's window shows that my window's DataContext property contains an instance of the ProjectManager class, so I know the DataContext is being set correctly and should be available to child controls.

Within the Window, my ComboBox has the following attributes set:

`ItemsSource="{Binding Projects, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentProject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Initially, the Projects observable collection is empty.  The expected behavior is that when the user clicks a button and I call Projects.Add( new Project( "ProjectName" ) ), the combobox should detect that the observable collection has changed and should add the new item to itself at the very least.  However, nothing appears in the combobox at all.

Comment: as you are adding Item from code why use Binding `Mode=OneWay`?

Comment: One way binding goes from source to target UI element.  A combobox will never update the collection, so the combobox must update when the collection changes.  That's one way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see your ObservableObject code?  I can't see anything wrong with your binding. If I implement what you've described as follows, everything works as intended which makes me think it's your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var Handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (Handler != null)
            Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Projects/DataContext:

```
public class ProjectManager : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public ProjectManager()
    {
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();

    }
    private Project loadedProject = null;
    public Project CurrentProject
    {
        get { return loadedProject; }
        set
        {
            //LoadProject(value); //load the project before updating internal variable
            //SetProperty(ref loadedProject, value); //SetProperty uses C# 5.0 [CallerMemberName] attribute on optional parameter to obtain "CurrentProject" property name since it's the caller; this is a popular implementation of ObservableObject
            loadedProject = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CurrentProject");
        }
    }
}

public class Project : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        //set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); } //ObservableObject implements INotifyProperyChanged
        set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name"); }
    }
}
```

Button Click:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectManager PM = DataContext as ProjectManager;

        PM.Projects.Add(new Project() { Name = "New  Project"});
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <pr:ProjectManager/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>     
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32">
            <Button Height="32" Click="Button_Click">Bind</Button>
            <ComboBox Height="32" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  
                  SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentProject}"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Result after Bind is pressed:

[image]

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question to include the ObservableObject code.

Comment: The problem isn't with the ObservableObject code, the problem is that the framework class ObservableCollection is not updating the ComboBox that it's bound to.

Comment: So, what's the difference between my example (where the ObservableCollection binds ok), and your actual code? Using your implementation of ObservableObject my test app also runs ok.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.  I've posted all the relevant code.  The ObservableCollection is dispatching the CollectionChange event, since I attached an event listener.  The ComboBox is just not receiving the event or is not updating itself for some reason.  Is has to be something with the binding, but it's bound correctly and the DataContext is present.

Comment: Dammit, nevermind, I found the problem.  My code is using a local variable for ProjectManager and is adding the new Project to that instead of the instance declared by the XAML.  Thank you for confirming that the code works.